# Applying color to forms in windows form application

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, windows-forms-designer

I change the color of the `form` at run time from a color pallet.

- How can I apply this color to all other `forms` of my application
  within one namespace?
- What if the forms are in different namespaces?

Comment: 1) create a global static variable. 2) change your forms constructors to take a Color variable which you store within the instance then assign the color to the form Background property in the form load event.

Answer (score 0):

creating unnecessary static variables in your application may cause lots of performance and memmory issues. Below will be a good solution to your needs.

Store a color as settings value on your application starts

```
Properties.Settings.Default.FormBackGroundColor = Color.Red; //your color here
```

In all other window initialize use below line

```
this.BackColor =  Properties.Settings.Default.FormBackGroundColor;
```